# Why can't i see the text of description in my url?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

In home category i have `elf` as a `description` :

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmTPF.png)

I tried this code in my views to be able to display `elf` in my templates:

```
def home(request ):
    p=get_object_or_404(category,pk=1)
    return render(request,'home.html',{'p':p})
```

and in templates i used this code `<p id="id">{{p.description}}</p>` to display it but it is not working i can not see the  `description` or `elf` in this path `path('',views.home),`

models:

```
class category(models.Model):

    name=models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class product(models.Model):
     
    category = models.ForeignKey(category, related_name='products',on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    image=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    price=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    buy=models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
    path('',views.home),
    path('admin/',admin.site.urls),
     
]
```

Why can't i see the  text of `description` in my url?

Comment: you are getting category not the product! `p=get_object_or_404(product,pk=1)`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the description of the category model. try this instead:

views:

```
def home(request ):
    p=get_object_or_404(product,pk=1)
    return render(request,'home.html',{'p':p})
```

Comment: I tried and I got this error: `No product matches the given query.`

Comment: try this:  `p=product.objects.filter(id=1).first()`

Comment: I tried but still don't see the `elf`.

Comment: try this way. and display your product information using for loop
def home(request ):
    p=product.objects.all()
    return render(request,'home.html',{'p':p})